# jQuery load file not working, blank page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to import the contents of a file (the file itself dosen't matter, html, php, text) - in all cases, I am unable to get any content loaded in. I've even used direct copy past off tutorials and it does not load or work?. I guess I'm missing something, or there is a version conflict maybe?.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">

 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#new").load("new.html);
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="new"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

This code is taken directly from jQuery website, I've only changed the file being loaded to "new.html" and yes, I have that named file in the same directoy.  I've tried both referencing the source from online, and using local jquery file, tried different browsers as well.

When testing, the browser shows a blank page, it's not displaying the text?.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: 1) create a non-black page without any scripts (put something inside the `new` div so you can determine a "blank" page compared with a "page with nothing on it".  Does that load ok?  2) press F12 and select "console" and look in there for errors as you load the page.   Are you running this from a file?  (eg is the url like: "file://c:\\yourpage.html")?

Comment: The given code is invalid, as you are missing a `"` after `new.html`

Comment: **NB:** As of jQuery 3, `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` has been deprecated in favour of `$(function(){ ... })` - [read the documentation for the reasoning](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks Richard for sharing that, it makes sense why it's not working.

Is there away to still do what I'm after, load the external document and have that div update automatically every X seconds?. 

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` is perfectly valid, it's just be *deprecated* (ie may be removed in later versions, but is still available in 3.6).  It's certainly available in your 1.8.3.  This has no impact on your code working or not, as was pointed out FYI, not as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should do this instead of `JQuery`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#new").load("new.html");
});

// OR

$(function(){
  $("#new").load("new.html");
)};
```

And I would recommend using

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The reason this wasn't working is that `JQuery` is deprecated (meaning it shouldn't be used and will error most of the time) you should use `$` since it is not deprecated and is the new way to do it. Also you did `load("new.html)` you missed a extra `"`

Comment: In both cases it's not working for me, I must be doing something wrong. It dosen't load the "file.html" into the div 'new'.

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#new").load("file.html");
});
</script>

</head>

<div id="new"></div>

<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It doesn't look like you closed it. Type it exactly like this ```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="new"></div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#new").load("c:/users/USERNAME/PATH_TO_FILE/file.html");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also change file.html to your filename then add .html

Comment: After much evaluation of logs; it seems that freedomn-m was on the right track, it had an issue with the path, this is caused by CORSRequestNotHttp more info at https://docs.w3cub.com/http/cors/errors/corsrequestnothttp - I'll see how I go from here! thanks all so far :)